# Repeatedly rolling a fair 6 sided die

Tags: probability, statistics, dice

Suppose you repeatedly roll a fair 6 sided die. What is the probability that you obtain at least one 5 before the first 6?
Will this involve an infinite sum?

Comment: I somehow got my answer as 1.

Comment: Call the chance you roll a $5$ before a $6$ as $x$.  What is the chance you roll a $6$ before a $5$?  And therefore...

Comment: “At least one” $\equiv$ which will you roll first, a or b?

Comment: What are a and b here?

Comment: Well you can either observe the probability tree and sum all cases which will be a infinite geometric sum, or... use the trick @DavidG.Stork gave you to deduce the result right away (Hint: rolling $x$ before $y$ is equivalent as rolling $y$ before $x$ since the dice is fair and symmetric, and both events are opposite, so combining these two facts tells you... what?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to calculate the complementary event, namely $A$, that is: the probability that you don't roll a five before the first six. Then this probability is an infinite sum, that is, the sum over $n$ that the probability that you get the first six in the $n$-th roll and no five in the previous rolls, namely the event $A_n$, i.e.:

$$
\Pr [A]= \sum_{n\geqslant 1}\Pr [A_n]=\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\left(\frac46\right)^{n-1}\frac16=\frac16\cdot \frac1{1-\frac46}=\frac12
$$
Then the probability that you want is $1-\Pr[A]=\frac12$.

Alternatively, following the comment of @David you can notice that the probability to get a five before a six is the same probability to get a six before a five, and each one is the complementary event of each other.

Answer (score 1):

Rolling a 5 or a 6 are equally likely. In this very simple joint probability space, that makes the events of rolling a 5 or 6 essentially interchangeable. You could put a sticker on the 5 and 6 sides that read "6" and "5" respectively, and nothing at all would change about your experiment. Because of this symmetry, the chance of rolling a 5 before a 6 must be the same as rolling a 6 before a 5, which is therefore 50%.

Answer (score 0):

If you roll anything other than a $5$ or a $6$ then the process effectively starts over, with no effect whatsoever on the probability of rolling a $5$ before a $6$. On the other hand, if you roll a $5$, you might as well stop rolling since you know that, whenever you do manage to roll a $6$, it will have happened after rolling a $5$. We therefore only really care about a die roll that stops the process, i.e., if we roll either a $5$ or a $6$. These are equiprobable, so...